# Import @angular/core module in Angular2 Type Script service, 'require' is undefined

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

I have service and I am trying but I get error when I start page:
[image]

compiled .js file has

```
reuired('@angular/core')
```

What can I check?

Answer (score 2):

Just my experience with VS... regardless of the quick start tsconfig.json setting documented [here](https://angular.io/guide/quickstart)

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    ...
```

in VS I had to use

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "system",
```

module `commonjs` was generating modules with require not with `System.register([` check the generated .js file...

Comment: *Well, in case there are other errors.. it seems that this issue is solved. At least in my case, that was the way how to fix "require" error, caused by different module system being generated by TS compiler...*

Comment: When i have "system" in my tsconfig i have neew error:    Uncaught TypeError: Invalid System.register call. Anonymous System.register calls can only be made by modules loaded by SystemJS.import and not via script tags.